# Get unique values from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Here are the arrays I have:

```
var a = [A];
var b = [F, A];
var c = [B, A];
var d = [C, B, A];
var e = [D, C, B, A];
var f = [E, C, B, A];
var g = [G, E, C, B, A];
```

I would like to run a function and get a list of elements that only occur once, so the output should be:

```
[F, D, G]
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not array of arrays

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an object. Use the values as keys, and increment every time the value shows up, then filter the keys to find the ones with value of 1.

Comment: @ecc521 good idea. I am going to try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object to store the frequency of each value and get only the entries where the frequency is one. The code below uses `.flat(Infinity)` to ensure that it works for any level of nested arrays; if you do not have any nested arrays, simply using [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) will work.

```js
var a = ['A'];
var b = ['F', 'A'];
var c = ['B', 'A'];
var d = ['C', 'B', 'A'];
var e = ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A'];
var f = ['E', 'C', 'B', 'A'];
var g = ['G', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'A'];
function getUniqueValues(...args){
  return Object.entries(
      args.flat(Infinity)
          .reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr] = (acc[curr] ?? 0) + 1, acc), {})
    ).filter(([key,val])=>val===1).map(([key])=>key);
}
console.log(getUniqueValues(a,b,c,d,e,f,g));
```

Comment: Nicely done. Took me a minute to realize that this should be O(n). Appeared to be O(n^2) at first glance, but that's one fancy reduce call.

Comment: @ecc521 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this solution may not be good

```
const input: string[][] =
  [['A'],
  ['F', 'A'],
  ['B', 'A'],
  ['C', 'B', 'A'],
  ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
  ['E', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
  ['G', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'A']];
let output: string[] = [];
let flagged: string[] = [];

input.filter(innerArray => {
    innerArray.filter(elem => {
        if(!output.includes(elem) && !flagged.includes(elem))
            output.push(elem);
        else
        {
            flagged.push(elem);
            output = output.filter(i => { return i !== elem });
        }
    });
});

console.log(output);
```